# Angular 4 :leave animation not triggering

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

In my project, I have the following:

**slideInOut.ts**

```
module import { trigger, state, animate, transition, style } from '@angular/animations';

export const slideInOut = trigger('slideInOut', [
  state('*', style({
    transform: 'translateX(0)'
  })),

  // route 'enter' transition
  transition(':enter', [
    style({
      transform: 'translateX(100%)'
    }),
    animate('.3s ease-in-out', style({
      transform: 'translateX(0)'
    }))
  ]),

  // route 'leave' transition
  transition(':leave', [
    animate('.3s ease-in-out', style({
      transform: 'translateX(100%)'
    }))
  ])
]);
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { slideInOut } from '../../animations/slideInOut';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  animations: [
    slideInOut
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor() {}
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div @slideInOut>
  <button [routerLink]="['', { outlets: {'aux': null} }]">Test</button>
</div>
```

For some reason, the leave animation doesn't trigger. My component slides in correctly, but not out. It sits for `.3s` and then disappears. I've tried multiple CSS properties instead of transform and the same thing happens. I've also tried replacing `:leave` with `* => *` and `* => void` just to be sure. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your **:leave** animation does not happen is because the route has changed and so did you "canvas"/component.

The **:enter** trigger animates because your animation is defined within your *now active* route, and when you visit it the "canvas" is there from the beginning.

Basically you need to think outside the box in our case `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

One way you can do it is is to wrap the **router-outlet** in a div container that will be animated, and the trigger for that animation will be route changes, you can listen for these in a bunch of ways.

Firstly I've added data to our routes to differentiate them:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { state: 'home' }  },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: { state: 'about' } },
];
```

We can then wrap the **router-outlet** in `app.component.html` like this:

```
<main [@routerTransition]="getState(o)">
  <router-outlet #o="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

The **getState()** method in `app.component.ts` handles the route change detection and triggers the animations:

```
getState(outlet) {
  // Changing the activatedRouteData.state triggers the animation
  return outlet.activatedRouteData.state;
}
```

And at the end we have the **animation** simply attached to the app component's decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('routerTransition', [
      transition('* <=> *', [    
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'fixed', width:'100%' })),
        group([ 
          query(':enter', [
            style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }),
            animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
          ]),
          query(':leave', [
            style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
            animate('0.5s ease-in-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))]),
        ])
      ])
    ])
   ],
})
```

You can check out this in practice here:

### [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-transitions?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Interesting that this approach does not work with child routes. Have you ever experienced that before?

Comment: @OtacilioOliveiraLimaNeto I cracked my brain before realized that `:leave` animation was not working for children routes. After converting children routes to direct paths animation starts working.

Comment: How can this be combined with component level animations as well? 

I am trying to animate the page in/out which is solved by this answer but when trying to animate in/out page elements at the component level nothing animates 

The idea is to recreate these kinds of transitions
 
https://miro.medium.com/max/7200/1*wF-43O9NF_nakKNMGbguqg.gif